# Stepping over `brk` instructions in lldb on AArch64

Tags: lldb, arm64

I'm working on a JIT compiler on the ARM64 platform.  In order to debug the machine code it emits, sometimes I will have the compiler emit a `brk` instruction so that I can inspect the state of things using lldb.

Unlike the x86_64 platform, the PC register is *at* the instruction (not after it):

```
Process 61859 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1008e8020)
    frame #0: 0x00000001008e8020
->  0x1008e8020: brk    #0x1
    0x1008e8024: ldur   x9, [x9]
    0x1008e8028: mov    x10, #0x4000
    0x1008e802c: movk   x10, #0x8e, lsl #16
Target 0: (ruby) stopped.
(lldb) p/x $pc
(unsigned long) $3 = 0x00000001008e8020
(lldb)
```

This means I cannot use `si` in lldb to step over the `brk` instruction because the `brk` instruction will just be evaluated over and over:

```
Process 61859 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1008e8020)
    frame #0: 0x00000001008e8020
->  0x1008e8020: brk    #0x1
    0x1008e8024: ldur   x9, [x9]
    0x1008e8028: mov    x10, #0x4000
    0x1008e802c: movk   x10, #0x8e, lsl #16
Target 0: (ruby) stopped.
(lldb) p/x $pc
(unsigned long) $3 = 0x00000001008e8020
(lldb) si
Process 61859 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1008e8020)
    frame #0: 0x00000001008e8020
->  0x1008e8020: brk    #0x1
    0x1008e8024: ldur   x9, [x9]
    0x1008e8028: mov    x10, #0x4000
    0x1008e802c: movk   x10, #0x8e, lsl #16
Target 0: (ruby) stopped.
(lldb) si
Process 61859 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1008e8020)
    frame #0: 0x00000001008e8020
->  0x1008e8020: brk    #0x1
    0x1008e8024: ldur   x9, [x9]
    0x1008e8028: mov    x10, #0x4000
    0x1008e802c: movk   x10, #0x8e, lsl #16
Target 0: (ruby) stopped.
(lldb)
```

I know that I can directly write to the `$pc` register to step over the instruction, but I don't want to copy / paste the next address every time.  I used to use this command:

```
register write $pc `$pc + 4`
```

But something changed on macOS such that the above command doesn't work anymore.  I get the following error:

> error: Failed to write register 'pc' with value '$pc + 4': '$pc + 4' is not a valid unsigned integer string value

Is there a better or more supported way to step over `brk` instructions on ARM64?  I'm currently using this version of lldb:

```
$ lldb -v
lldb-1403.0.17.64
Apple Swift version 5.8 (swiftlang-5.8.0.124.2 clang-1403.0.22.11.100)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this [is a bug in Apple's version of lldb](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/stepping-over-a-brk-instruction-on-arm64/69766/2)

Comment: To be pedantic, it's a bug that was in the mainline version of lldb for a while, and was just recently fixed there, but the fix hasn't made it into an Xcode release yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is an orthogonal answer:

The difference between the x86_64 and AARCH64 behavior is actually a hardware difference.  x86_64 executes it's break instruction before raising the exception, whereas ARM raises the exception when it sees the `brk` instruction, but doesn't execute it.

Starting with lldb-1403.0.17.64, lldb will recognize the special trap that `__builtin_debugtrap()` inserts, and auto-step over that one for you on systems that don't execute their break instructions.  So for instance:

```
(lldb) run
Process 12749 launched: '/tmp/has_break' (arm64)
I am here
Process 12749 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100003f78)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003f7c has_break`main at has_break.c:9
   6    main()
   7    {
   8      printf("I am here\n");
-> 9      __builtin_debugtrap();
          ^
   10     printf("Am I still?\n");
   11   }
Target 0: (has_break) stopped.
(lldb) dis -f
has_break`main:
    0x100003f64 <+0>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x100003f68 <+4>:  mov    x29, sp
    0x100003f6c <+8>:  adrp   x0, 0
    0x100003f70 <+12>: add    x0, x0, #0xfa0            ; "I am here\n"
    0x100003f74 <+16>: bl     0x100003f94               ; symbol stub for: printf
    0x100003f78 <+20>: brk    #0xf000
->  0x100003f7c <+24>: adrp   x0, 0
    0x100003f80 <+28>: add    x0, x0, #0xfab            ; "Am I still?\n"
    0x100003f84 <+32>: bl     0x100003f94               ; symbol stub for: printf
    0x100003f88 <+36>: mov    w0, #0x0
    0x100003f8c <+40>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x100003f90 <+44>: ret
```

Note, the pc is already past the `brk`...

So if you can use the `__builtin_debugtrap()` instead of the brk you are manually inserting, then you can dispense with your step over it logic.

Comment: Manually using `0xf000` for my `brk` instruction worked for me. Thanks for the answer!